# How to use different values for variables in different targets of the same Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, targets

I have a project with the same code base for different targets, which need different values for some variables. What is the best way to achieve that? Here are my thoughts:

- Use a different property list resource containing the values for each target. Con: I have to parse the property list at runtime to get the values. The values appear in clear if someone looks inside the application bundle.
- Use `#define`s in different include files. Con: For each new target, I have to use macro conditionals to include the correct file in the implementation.
- Use a different implementation file for each target:

  - with constant global variables. Con: The namespace is polluted by these global variables.
  - with a class whose properties are the variables. Con: Each implementation has to rewrite the glue code for the properties.

Does anyone has a good solution? Or is better to factor the common code base into a library and use different projects each time?

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution for this?